# swift, retrieve changed data from tableViewCells that have CustomCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, custom-cell

This question has been asked a couple of times in lots of places, but it is extremely difficult to understand and solve it.

My problem is different, and I am asking this question after researching for more than 5 hours.

I have a tableView where I have 3 different types of CustomCells.

My custom cells have 3 things, 2 common a Label and a TextField. 3rd item (stepper, button, switch)

I have dynamically placed 10 cells calling

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

What I want to do ideally ->

When my users change the data on the cells, I would like to get all the 'updated' data so I can save it to my database when I click 'Save'.

I tried using

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
```

and using breakpoints, apparently the codeblock gets triggered when I touch the cell. Unfortunately, touch means literally touching the list entry body.

if I use the UI items (stepper/switch) which are within my custom cell, this code portion does not get triggered.

I have seen solutions using Tags and Delegates, but since I am new to iOS, I am not sure how to implement or go ahead. I am using Angela's Udemy iOS course to teach myself.

Custom Cell
[image]

Overall screen, I like to get the textfield values, when user changes them
[image: Screenshot of dynamically populated tableview]

Comment: So are you trying to handle each individual touch/action events from the steppers/switches inside the cells?

Comment: I have attached photos, if you imagine the full screen as a form, I would like to get all the current values the screen has

Comment: Both photos are the same. I'm writing out an answer right now.

Comment: derp. Updated the images :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Tested) 
Hello, one way in which I used to solve this was to add the handler function outside of the subclass inside where you have initialized your tableView.

```
    //.... This is your cellForRowAt tableView function..
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId) as! cellSubclass
    cell.stepperButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleStep(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    return cell
}

@objc func handleStep(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    print(sender.value)
    let indexPath : IndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0) 
    // Put the correct item # to locate where you have the stepper,
    // Then create a separate function doing the same thing, but with the item 
    // number of the next cell where you get the value from the switch
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! cellSubclass
    cell.textField.text = "\(Int(sender.value))"
}
```

You are connecting the UIStepper through the addTarget method inside of the function where you are creating your cells.

Here is a picture of my result: [image]

Tip: add `stepper.minimumValue = 0`
This disables the [ - ] button when the value == 0.

Comment: This works! I have a feeling it is not the right way to go. Because, my custom cell has a 'label' and 'textfield', I feel like I have to create another 'addTarget' to get the label. And, for every different cell, I have to do the same? Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: For your first question about the label, just call it from the same function, ex: inside the handleStep, after "let cell = ...", print(cell.labelName.text)

Comment: For the other cells, ( I saw there was just two so I thought it wouldn't be too much work this way ), yes you just add another addTarget inside your cellForRowAt.  Ex: if indexPath.row == 0 { cell.stepper.addTarget.... } else { cell.switch.addTarget..... }. And if you add more cells with more functions, you could use a switch statement.  Yes there is probably a cleaner way to do this, but I am just going off of what I know :) lol

Comment: For now, it is of amazing help! Thanks for helping, as I am new to this, I am sure I will pick up more and cleaner techniques to handle my code. :)

Comment: Kind of a stupid question, but what is a good way to pass the item number of IndexPath over to the #selector method please?